# Can we have the ability to filter favorites by tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags, bookmarks

I would love to have the ability to filter my favorites by tags.  I store a bunch of questions tagged with specific technologies and have trouble finding them.  Does this feature currently exist and I'm missing it?  Is this something that could be implemented?

For example, I was just searching for a question I made a favorite awhile ago regarding conditional commits using Git.  I had to page through my favorites and search for "Git" using the browser.  One search per page, ugh!  It would have been so much easier if I could have just looked through my favorites tagged with Git.  I could almost see something similar to a developers playbook that would be very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this via the [**search page**](https://stackoverflow.com/search) using the parameter `infavorites:mine` and the `[tag]`.

> [image]
>
> [image]